# Export/import/backup RedisGraph database

Tags: database, redis, backup, redis-cli, redisgraph

I've got a little too far with RedisGraph and now it's about to ship in production.

Therefore I need to export and import some data between servers and also to create backups.
I'm using the open source community version (not the Redis Entreprise).

How would you recommend to proceed backups and imports/exports?

Thanks for your feedbacks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RedisGraph stores each graph in a single Redis key, so traditional Redis persistency methods can be used to persist and migrate data.

Backups are usually managed using RDB files or a combination of both the RDB and AOF strategies, these are described [here](https://redis.io/topics/persistence).

If your Redis keyspace should be entirely duplicated or only consists of graph keys, you can copy the RDB file between servers, otherwise you can export and import graph keys with the [DUMP](https://redis.io/commands/dump) and RESTORE commands.

Comment: Great, thanks! And I could find my dump folder running `cat /usr/local/etc/redis.conf | grep "^dir "`